# /tmp permission denied while trying to run `npm run build` on linux

Tags: linux, deployment, permission-denied, tmp, npm-run

I've laravel application deployed to Linux/Debian server, one of the steps that I have to do is to run `npm run build` for production
I got the following error:

```
npm run build

> build
> vite build

/tmp/build-ade1100b.sh: 1: vite: Permission denied
```

I tried to do this with sudo privilege, another user has sudo privilege too, it didn't work, I know this is a sticky folder, I tries too many solutions but no one work with me.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete your `node_modules` folder using `rm -rf node_modules/`
2. Reinstall the modules using `npm i` or `yarn install`

`npm run build` should now work again.